# I'm not getting flush to work

Tags: php, ajax, flush

I have the following script:

```
function follow($file)
{
    $currentSize = filesize($file);
    $size = $currentSize;
    $index=0;
    while ($index<$currentSize) {
    //echo "ENTERING   LOOP!!!!";
        clearstatcache();
        $currentSize = filesize($file);
        if ($size == $currentSize) {
            usleep(100);
            continue;
        }

        $fh = fopen($file, "r");
        fseek($fh, $size);

        while ($d = fgets($fh)) {
        ob_end_flush();
                echo $d;
        ob_flush();
        flush();
        ob_start();
        }

        fclose($fh);
        $size = $currentSize;
    $index=$index+1;
    }
}

follow("/var/www/devicemanagement/testFile.txt");
```

This script echoes a log file in real time and it works well when run in command line.

The following html code is meant to display the echoed lines from the php script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
        <script>

            var sentData = {
                'param1': 'value1',
                'param2': 'value2'
            };

            function successCallback(returnedData) {
                $('#myDiv').html(returnedData);
            }

            function doAjaxCall() {
                $.get('/labtool/controllers/tailor.php', sentData, successCallback);
                //$.get('testFile.php', sentData, successCallback);
            }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                var id;
                $('#doStuff').click(function () {
                    clearInterval(id);
                    //$.get('testFile.php', sentData, successCallback);
                });
                id = setInterval(doAjaxCall, 1000);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
        <button type="button" id="doStuff">Change Content</button>
        <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I understand the key is using flush right, but despite my best efforts and a lot of experimenting I'm unable to get it to work.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using info I gathered from probably many sources including stackoverflow, sorry about the formatting.  Every time you have text to flush, simply call the function:

```
function flush_message($msg) 
{


    echo $msg;
      // not a space, just '', I haven't tried removing it to see what happens
      // cause I should really be working on something else right now!
      echo str_pad('', 4096) . "\n";
      ob_flush();
      flush();

}
```

I also set

```
apache_setenv('no-gzip', 1);
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
```

at the beginning of script

Apparently there are lots of browser specific issues as well (regarding how big buffer until output is drawn) so you might want to test on different platforms to see how it performs.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm still a newbie at php so sometimes not even what seems to be clear answers are so clear for me. Your solution doesn't work with my setting it seems. Still nothing happens, I will experiment further with it thou. Thanks